# Destinguish between types

Tags: c++, types

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned char type1;
typedef unsigned long type2;

type1 f(type1 value)
{
    return value * 2;
}

int main()
{
  type1 value1 = 1;
  type2 value2 = 2000;
  int int1 = f(value1);
  int int2 = f(value2);  // here I would expect that the compiler warns me that I mix type1 and type2
  std::cout << int1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << int2 << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way that the compiler warns me if I mix the two types type1 (unsigned char) and type2 (unsigned long)?

Thanks
Teddy

Comment: fwiw, you can remove the `typedef`s, they dont change anything on the question and reduce readability a bit

Comment: Are you aware of the possibility to configure compilers to be very nitpicky? I.e. things like `-Wall` etc? Is that what you want?

Comment: @Yunnosch was going to comment the same, but there is no reason to warn here, a `char` always fits inside a `long` (or `int`)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Hmmm. The parameter type is `unsigned char` the `value2` is 2000. That does not match your statement, does it?

Comment: @Yunnosch ups sorry, got confused by the typedefs, though I dont get a warning with `-Wall` from gcc...

Comment: @idclev463035818 No wonder. Your first comment is to the point...

Comment: @idclev463035818 `-Wall` doesn't actually mean all possible warnings, but a set of commonly wanted warnings. `-Wall -Wextra` gets stricter with more warnings, but some like `-Wconversion` are considered so rarely wanted that they must be specified individually.

Comment: @aschepler thanks for clarification. I remembered something like that, still I would have expected that `-Wall` would be sufficient to catch this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way that the compiler warns me if I mix the two types type1 (unsigned char) and type2 (unsigned long)?

Yes, if you give `-Wconversion` to gcc or clang, or `/W3` to MSVC, they will print a warning for your example.

(They will only warn you, if there is a potential value change. So, converting `unsigned char` to `unsigned long` generates no warning, as this conversion always retains value)